# Add error correction information to piped tar stream

Tags: linux, backup, archiving, error-correction

I'm using Amazon S3 Glacier Deep Archive to store backups on my Ubuntu machine. My workflow basically boils down to:

```
tar cf - $FILES | gzip -3 --stdout | aws s3 cp - $TARGET
```

I think this works quite nicely, but with very large archives (1TB+) I am worried that if my PC messes up somewhere, or a bit flips, the entire archive will become unusable.
Ideally I want to add some error correction capability to this flow.

I looked at PAR2, which seems to do what I want, with one caveat: it cannot take a pipe as input. It would require me to build the entire archive on disk, *then* run it through PAR2 and then upload everything. With archives of over 1TB, this is not always feasible in terms of available disk space, let alone that is slows down the process considerably.

I could not find any similar tool to add forward error correction information to a stream of data without saving it to a file first. How can I do this? It doesn't really matter if a solution adds the information to a separate file, or modifies the stream to add redundancy.

Answer (score 1):

#### Tool: `redupe`

I found a tool for this: `redupe`. Read about it: [*Redupe: Forward Error Correction*](https://hack.systems/2018/05/16/redupe/).

> This post introduces the `redupe` […] tool for providing forward error correction to streams of data. […] `redupe`, is modeled after compression tools like `gzip` or `bzip2` , but adds redundancy instead of eliminating it. `redupe` operates on the data directly, transforming it into its redundant state by adding the redundant information inline with the original data.

The complementary command is `reundupe`, it's really just one tool and the name you call it by decides what it does.

You can get `redupe` [from GitHub](https://github.com/rescrv/redupe).

I managed to compile and test `redupe` in my Debian 12. See below for details.

---

#### Compilation

<sup>Note: some problems described here may have occurred because I lack experience with programming and compiling, or maybe because I hadn't configured everything right beforehand (or at all).</sup>

My OS is Debian 12. This is what I did:

1. I downloaded `redupe-master.zip` [from GitHub](https://github.com/rescrv/redupe), unzipped and placed myself in newly-created `redupe-master/`.
2. By trials and errors I discovered I need the following packages: `automake`, `make`, `gcc`, `libpopt-dev`, `libtool`*.

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install automake make gcc libpopt-dev libtool
   ```

   <sup>* At least these packages are what I have tried and they all seemed important.</sup>
3. ```
   autoreconf -ivf
   ```
4. ```
   ./configure && make && sudo make install
   ```
5. I was able to start `redupe`, but the tool wasn't able to find `libredupe.so.0`. I discovered the relevant libraries are in `/usr/local/lib/`. With `strace redupe` I discovered that the tool checks several locations (e.g. `/usr/lib/`) but not `/usr/local/lib/`. I moved everything related to `redupe` from `/usr/local/lib/` to `/usr/lib/:

   ```
   sudo mv /usr/local/lib/libredupe.* /usr/lib/
   ```
6. I also discovered that newly installed `/usr/local/bin/redupe` and `/usr/local/bin/reundupe` are identical regular files. One regular file is enough, the other name can be a symlink:

   ```
   (cd /usr/local/bin/ && sudo rm reundupe && sudo ln -s redupe reundupe)
   ```

---

#### My test

1. I piped 1 GiB from `/dev/urandom` to a regular file `original`.
2. I piped `original` through `redupe` and saved the result as `original.rd`.
3. I piped `original.rd` through `tr ab xy` to change some bytes, saved the result as `modified.rd`.
4. I made sure `original.rd` and `modified.rd` are different (one can use `cmp` or `md5sum` or such). It's very, very unlikely there is no `a` and no `b` in 1 GiB of random data, so this step is not really needed.
5. I piped `modified.rd` through `reundupe` and saved the result as `result`.
6. I checked (with `cmp`) if `original` and `result` are identical.

The above procedure uses several regular files. With reduced number of regular files the procedure looks like this:

```
</dev/urandom head -c 1G >original \
&& <original redupe | tr ab xy | reundupe | cmp - original
```

Successful `cmp` (no error, exit status 0) means `redupe` works. It works for me.

I also tested without `tr` (`… | redupe | reundupe | …`) to see if everything is fine when there is no corruption at all. It is.

---

#### Conclusion, notes

- `redupe` works, but it's not a cure-all. Keep reading.
- Invoke `redupe --help`, note the `-o`/`--overhead` option.
- If data is too damaged for `reundupe` to correct it then the tool will print `error reading input`; slightly misleading, be warned.
- I managed to find a (relatively small) file of random data that after applying `redupe -o 1` (weak redundancy), altering (relatively strongly) and applying `reundupe` gave me a different file without any error from `reundupe`. I don't really suspect a bug, by chance I probably managed to create a file that appeared valid for `reundupe`. OTOH occasional bit flips were corrected fine.
- While occasional bit flips (and byte flips) were corrected fine, missing or excessive bytes in the stream were *fatal*. It seems the tool is not designed to correct this kind of errors.
- You wrote "I am worried that if my PC messes up somewhere". If your PC messes up before `redupe` then `redupe` will work with a messed up stream and dutifully process it. Garbage in, garbage out; `reundupe` will recreate the original messed up stream. If your PC (or whatever) *really* messes up after `redupe` then most likely the tool won't help you either because it handles bit flips only.
- `redupe` works inside a pipe and this is what you wanted. But this also means that it has to process data using a relatively small window. Several corrupted bytes close one to another will be worse than the same number of corrupted bytes scattered all over a large file.
- You want to put `redupe` between `gzip` and `aws`, not before `gzip`. Then, while retrieving from backup, `reundupe` will be before `gunzip`. Doing this the other way around (i.e. `redupe` before `gzip`, `gunzip` before `reundupe`) is flawed because:

  - (practical reason) a bit flip will make `gunzip` fail ([it checks CRC](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/160233/108618)) and data won't even get to `reundupe` to be corrected; but even if you could make `gunzip` continue, there is another reason; which is…
  - (theoretical reason) compression works by detecting patterns, similarities, so it reduces redundancy; you don't want to add redundancy and remove it right away; you want to reduce redundancy of your actual data, then add some deliberate redundancy and *keep it*.
- For now it seems to me `redupe`+`reundupe` properly and firmly works when there is no corruption; it can repair minor corruption (changed bytes). Corruption that apparently "exceeds the redundancy" may or may not be detected by `reundupe` (in your case an undetected corruption will probably make `gunzip` fail though). In other words the tool does not corrupt good data and it gives you some chances to recover good data from corrupt data. In my opinion the net value of the tool is positive for sure.
- Conduct your own tests and decide if `redupe` is good for you; and what `--overhead` you want; and if the performance is acceptable.